# how to pass fieldset value to a mvc controller using minicart.js

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, paypal, shopping-cart

I am using minicart.js for a personal project. Here I have fieldset value that I add as cart item:

```
 <fieldset>
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />
<input type="hidden" name="add" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="business" value=" " />
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="@pro.Name" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="@pro.SalesRate" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add to cart" class="button" />
</fieldset>
```

Here is my js:

```
paypal.minicart.cart.on('checkout', function (evt) {

        var items = this.items(),
            len = items.length,
            total = 0,
            i;

        for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
            total += items[i].get('quantity');
            Productname = items[i].get('item_name');
            productPrice = items[i].get('amount');
        }

    });
```

After checkout the cart item it redirects to a controller. This is minicart.js code:

```
var defaults = module.exports = {

name: 'PPMiniCart',

parent: (typeof document !== 'undefined') ? document.body : null,

action: '/Home/CheckOut',

target: '',

duration: 30,

template: '<%var items = cart.items();var settings = cart.settings();var hasItems = !!items.length;var priceFormat = { format: true, currency: cart.settings("currency_code") };var totalFormat = { format: true, showCode: true };%><form method="post" class="<% if (!hasItems) { %>minicart-empty<% } %>" action="<%= config.action %>" target="<%= config.target %>">    <button type="button" class="minicart-closer">&times;</button>    <ul>        <% for (var i= 0, idx = i + 1, len = items.length; i < len; i++, idx++) { %>        <li class="minicart-item">            <div class="minicart-details-name">                <a class="minicart-name" href="<%= items[i].get("href") %>"><%= items[i].get("item_name") %></a>                <ul class="minicart-attributes">                    <% if (items[i].get("item_number")) { %>                    <li>                        <%= items[i].get("item_number") %>                        <input type="hidden" name="item_number_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].get("item_number") %>" />                    </li>                    <% } %>                    <% if (items[i].discount()) { %>                    <li>                        <%= config.strings.discount %> <%= items[i].discount(priceFormat) %>                        <input type="hidden" name="discount_amount_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].discount() %>" />                    </li>                    <% } %>                    <% for (var options = items[i].options(), j = 0, len2 = options.length; j < len2; j++) { %>                        <li>                            <%= options[j].key %>: <%= options[j].value %>                            <input type="hidden" name="on<%= j %>_<%= idx %>" value="<%= options[j].key %>" />                            <input type="hidden" name="os<%= j %>_<%= idx %>" value="<%= options[j].value %>" />                        </li>                    <% } %>                </ul>            </div>            <div class="minicart-details-quantity">                <input class="minicart-quantity" data-minicart-idx="<%= i %>" name="quantity_<%= idx %>" type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" value="<%= items[i].get("quantity") %>" autocomplete="off" />            </div>            <div class="minicart-details-remove">                <button type="button" class="minicart-remove" data-minicart-idx="<%= i %>">&times;</button>            </div>            <div class="minicart-details-price">                <span class="minicart-price"><%= items[i].total(priceFormat) %></span>            </div>            <input type="hidden" name="item_name_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].get("item_name") %>" />            <input type="hidden" name="amount_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].amount() %>" />            <input type="hidden" name="shipping_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].get("shipping") %>" />            <input type="hidden" name="shipping2_<%= idx %>" value="<%= items[i].get("shipping2") %>" />        </li>        <% } %>    </ul>    <div class="minicart-footer">        <% if (hasItems) { %>            <div class="minicart-subtotal">                <%= config.strings.subtotal %> <%= cart.total(totalFormat) %>            </div>            <button class="minicart-submit" type="submit" data-minicart-alt="<%= config.strings.buttonAlt %>"><%- config.strings.button %></button>        <% } else { %>            <p class="minicart-empty-text"><%= config.strings.empty %></p>        <% } %>    </div>    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" />    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1" />    <% for (var key in settings) { %>        <input type="hidden" name="<%= key %>" value="<%= settings[key] %>" />    <% } %></form>',

styles: '@keyframes pop-in {    0% { opacity: 0; transform: scale(0.1); }    60% { opacity: 1; transform: scale(1.2); }    100% { transform: scale(1); }}@-webkit-keyframes pop-in {    0% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: scale(0.1); }    60% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: scale(1.2); }    100% { -webkit-transform: scale(1); }}@-moz-keyframes pop-in {    0% { opacity: 0; -moz-transform: scale(0.1); }    60% { opacity: 1; -moz-transform: scale(1.2); }    100% { -moz-transform: scale(1); }}.minicart-showing #PPMiniCart {    display: block;    transform: translateZ(0);    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);    animation: pop-in 0.25s;    -webkit-animation: pop-in 0.25s;    -moz-animation: pop-in 0.25s;}#PPMiniCart {    display: none;    position: fixed;    left: 50%;    top: 75px;}#PPMiniCart form {    position: relative;    width: 400px;    max-height: 400px;    margin-left: -200px;    padding: 10px 10px 40px;    background: #fbfbfb;    border: 1px solid #d7d7d7;    border-radius: 4px;    box-shadow: 2px 2px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);    font: 15px/normal arial, helvetica;    color: #333;}#PPMiniCart form.minicart-empty {    padding-bottom: 10px;    font-size: 16px;    font-weight: bold;}#PPMiniCart ul {    clear: both;    float: left;    width: 380px;    margin: 5px 0 20px;    padding: 10px;    list-style-type: none;    background: #fff;    border: 1px solid #ccc;    border-radius: 4px;    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);}#PPMiniCart .minicart-empty ul {    display: none;}#PPMiniCart .minicart-closer {    float: right;    margin: -12px -10px 0;    padding: 10px;    background: 0;    border: 0;    font-size: 18px;    cursor: pointer;    font-weight: bold;}#PPMiniCart .minicart-item {    clear: left;    padding: 6px 0;    min-height: 25px;}#PPMiniCart .minicart-item + .minicart-item {    border-top: 1px solid #f2f2f2;}#PPMiniCart .minicart-item a {    color: #333;    text-decoration: none;}#PPMiniCart .minicart-details-name {    float: left;    width: 62%;}#PPMiniCart .minicart-details-quantity {    float: left;    width: 15%;}#PPMiniCart .minicart-details-remove {    float: left;    width: 7%;}#PPMiniCart .minicart-details-price {    float: left;    width: 16%;    text-align: right;}#PPMiniCart .minicart-attributes {    margin: 0;    padding: 0;    background: transparent;    border: 0;    border-radius: 0;    box-shadow: none;    color: #999;    font-size: 12px;    line-height: 22px;}#PPMiniCart .minicart-attributes li {    display: inline;}#PPMiniCart .minicart-attributes li:after {    content: ",";}#PPMiniCart .minicart-attributes li:last-child:after {    content: "";}#PPMiniCart .minicart-quantity {    width: 30px;    height: 18px;    padding: 2px 4px;    border: 1px solid #ccc;    border-radius: 4px;    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);    font-size: 13px;    text-align: right;    transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;    -webkit-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;    -moz-transition: border linear 0.2s, box-shadow linear 0.2s;}#PPMiniCart .minicart-quantity:hover {    border-color: #0078C1;}#PPMiniCart .minicart-quantity:focus {    border-color: #0078C1;    outline: 0;    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 3px rgba(0, 120, 193, 0.4);}#PPMiniCart .minicart-remove {    width: 18px;    height: 19px;    margin: 2px 0 0;    padding: 0;    background: #b7b7b7;    border: 1px solid #a3a3a3;    border-radius: 3px;    color: #fff;    font-size: 13px;    opacity: 0.70;    cursor: pointer;}#PPMiniCart .minicart-remove:hover {    opacity: 1;}#PPMiniCart .minicart-footer {    clear: left;}#PPMiniCart .minicart-subtotal {    position: absolute;    bottom: 17px;    padding-left: 6px;    left: 10px;    font-size: 16px;    font-weight: bold;}#PPMiniCart .minicart-submit {    position: absolute;    bottom: 10px;    right: 10px;    min-width: 153px;    height: 33px;    margin-right: 6px;    padding: 0 9px;    border: 1px solid #ffc727;    border-radius: 5px;    color: #000;    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff6e9;    cursor: pointer;    background: #ffaa00;    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #fff6e9 0%, #ffaa00 100%);    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#fff6e9), color-stop(100%,#ffaa00));    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #fff6e9 0%,#ffaa00 100%);    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #fff6e9 0%,#ffaa00 100%);    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #fff6e9 0%,#ffaa00 100%);    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff6e9 0%,#ffaa00 100%);}#PPMiniCart .minicart-submit img {    vertical-align: middle;    padding: 4px 0 0 2px;}',

strings: {
    button: 'Check Out with <img src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/minicart/3.0.1/paypal_65x18.png" width="65" height="18" alt="PayPal" />',
    subtotal: 'Subtotal:',
    discount: 'Discount:',
    empty: 'Your shopping cart is empty'
}
```

but I can't figure out how to pass `productPrice,Productname` value to the `'/Home/CheckOut'` controller.
I am new in programming. Any kind of help is highly appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

you find fuction  **Cart.prototype.checkout** in minicart.js

```
 Cart.prototype.checkout = function checkout(evt)
    {
        var items = this.items(),
            data = [],
            i, len;
        var cartList = [];

        for (i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++)
        {
            data.push(items[i].get());
            cartList.push(
                {
                    Productname = items[i].get('item_name');
                    productPrice = items[i].get('amount');
                });
        }
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: '/Home/CheckOut',
            data: { cartModel: JSON.stringify(cartList) },
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (res) {
                if (res.status === true) {

                }
            }
        });
        this.fire('checkout', evt);
    };
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks